# How can I control Background Music of other Apps in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, background-music

First sorry for my English because I'm French.

I work on a connected object which send data to my app to start, pause, start the next music or the precedent and to augment the volume.

My application has to execute these actions on any music emitted by the iPhone. For example, if I listen to music in Spotify or Deezer, the app has to control it.

I don't know how I can do this in Swift. Just I really think that work with `AVAudioSession`.

Comment: I doubt you *can* do that. You can play your own sounds, but not control others.

Comment: Okay... But how headphones remote and Bluetooth object can controle musics of an  iPhone ?

Comment: Those are hardware, you are building software. That are two very different things, following different rules and using different APIs

Comment: So there isn't any solutions ? I saw i'ts possible with the app Music..

Comment: Oh, and it's not possible to call a thing like a command Line, to control background Music ?

Comment: iOS doesn't have a command line, its not a mac or a pc. And an app doesn't have any access to nor ability to control to other apps

Comment: Okay you very much  for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking about, but I think this is what you mean. This will control the music playing on you device and the volume. 
Here's an article about it : http://www.justindoan.com/tutorials/2016/7/31/mpmedia-tutorial-control-music-playback-in-ios-with-swift

So here's basically what you have to do. Firstly import MediaPlayer.

```
    import MediaPlayer
```

then you define the mediaController and prepare to play

```
    let mediaController = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()
    mediaController.prepareToPlay()
```

and to control the media.

```
    //play
    mediaController.play()

    //pause
    mediaController.pause()

    //go to previous item
    mediaController.skipToPreviousItem()

    //go to start of the item
    mediaController.skipToBeginning()

    //and to go to the next item
    mediaController.skipToNextItem()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This just controls local songs, not background music of other apps.